# Why does the definition of the Fourier transform on Schwartz-Space also makes sense in $L_1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In the book "Classical Fourier Analysis by Grafakos"
the Fourier transform is first defined on $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$. In the Chapter 2.2.4 it is mentioned that the definition of the Fourier transform
$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} dx$
"makes sense" as a convergent integral for functions $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Here my question:

First I thought he meant that $\hat{f}(\xi)$ in $L_1$ can be approximated with a sequence.
But I think I did misinterpret it.
I did stumble over the following question:
[Showing existence of Fourier-Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716137/showing-existence-of-fourier-transform)

Reading through it, I now think that the "makes sense as"-part in the book was meant as a "the proof for $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ holds too for $L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$".
(In the Link only the case $n=1$ is discussed, but I think a very similar proof would do for $n \neq 1$)

Now my question:
Did I now understand it correctly? The "makes sense as"-part did just mean that the same proof also yields the existence of the FT for $L_1$, right?

Comment: I suppose it just means that the integral makes sense as a convergent Lebesgue integral, since $\int |f(x)\, e^{-2i\pi xy}|\,\mathrm dx = \int |f(x)|\,\mathrm dx$. By the way, $f(x)$ is missing in your definition of Fourier transform.

Comment: The Fourier transform makes sense for $f\in L^1.$ Moreover for $f\in S$ we have $\widehat{f}\in S,$ hence $\widehat{f}\in L^1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc (+1) for your comment, which is, I believe, precisely what the OP was asking.